# Accidentally Ignoring Changes After Pulling

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github, smartgit

I pulled the changes on the remote repository (using smartgit) then when I turned to Visual Studio to work, a window just popped up asking me some external changes made on VS and if I wanna accept them but I mistakenly clickled Ignore All instead of Yes. And I tried to pull the remote repo again but the updates did not show up on VS. How can I sync my local app with the remote repository?

Thanks

Comment: What does the SmartGit log look like? Based on what you said, it sounds like Visual Studio replaced all the new files, with the version you had opened.  These should show up as uncommitted changes.

Comment: Most likely that was just VS informing you that the files on the system had changed and do you want to view the changed files or keep what's in memory. Try shutting VS down and starting it back up again. You should be good to go.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer, if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with SmartGit, it relates to Visual Studio. Visual Studio has detected that content of your files changed outside of Visual Studio. Because you updated files in git. And it suggested you to reload those files. As JDB pointed out in the comments, it is enough to restart Visual Studio, or even just reopen the solution you are currently working on, to ensure you work with updated files.